# Next tab on `enter` - AngularMaterial

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using `angular-material` tabs in my app. I need to traverse through tabs changing `md-select` dynamically by controller function. This is my code

View:

```
<md-tabs  md-border-bottom md-selected="selectedIndex">
  <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" label="Label {{$index + 1}}"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

And this is how I am changing the value modeled with `md-select`

```
$scope.changeTab = function(){
  $scope.selectedIndex = ($scope.selectedIndex + 1) %  $scope.tabs.length;
}
```

Now there are two cases

**1st**:

If I create a button like `<button type='button' ng-click='changeTab()'>Button</button>`, clicking on this button works fine and I can successfully see the tabs moving clicking onthis `button`

**2nd**

Infact I need to move to the next tab when user hits `enter`. So what I did for that is

```
$document.bind('keypress', function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = ($scope.selectedIndex + 1) %  $scope.tabs.length;
  }
});
```

But this shows random behavior. Sometimes it moves to next tab and sometimes not. I've different kind of input fields on each tab. Hitting enter only works for those tabs which have `input of type text`. And for anything else, I had to click on somewhere after hitting enter, then it moves to the next tab. I need it to move to the next tab whenever user hits enter. What am I doing wrong or missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that you're updating the tab index outside of angular $digest cicle. To quickly fix you code, wrap the this line inside `$timeout()` or `$scope.$applyAsync()`... ([PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/f1NYVROyAkUYAhCBPiyN?p=preview))

```
$scope.$applyAsync(function () {
  $scope.selectedIndex = ($scope.selectedIndex + 1) %  $scope.tabs.length;
});
```

---

**Option using `ng-keypess` directive over body tag:** ([PLUNKER NG-KEYPRESS](https://plnkr.co/edit/cJJA8psSaxpJ80szjFQ8?p=preview))

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="ChipsController as vm" ng-keypress="changeTab($event)">
  <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex">
    <!-- rest of your code -->
```

**JS:**

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  //...    
  $scope.changeTab = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
      $scope.selectedIndex = ($scope.selectedIndex + 1) %  $scope.tabs.length;
  };
}
```